# How do I move some cell values from 2 columns in Pandas DF to another new column?

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

So I am working on the below dataframe:

[image: DF]

What I am trying to do is merge the numeric values of 2 columns ('elected_in' & 'campaigned_in_') into a new column.

This column should look like this

**new_column**

- 007
- NaN
- 043
- 275
- 027
- etc

Any tips on how to do this at all? Found all the stack overflow answers not quite pertaining to this and I am also not sure what terminology to use...

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically combine them using `new` column. I'm suggesting this as you have number and string both as value in the columns that you're trying to merge. Please refer below code.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[7, "Bremen", "test"], [4, 5, 6], ["trial", 8, 43]]),
                   columns=['elected', 'b', 'campained'])
```

[image]

```py
# Now combine them
df['number'] = df['elected'] + " " +df['campained']
df.head()
```

[image]

If you only want numbers then you can use simple `lambda` function to do that.

```py
import re as re

def find_number(text):
    num = re.findall(r'[0-9]+',text)
    return " ".join(num)

df['new']=df['number'].apply(lambda x: find_number(x))
df.head()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over rows using `iterrows()` method and replace value on condition (if value in `campaigned_in` is a string replace with that from `elected_in`)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"elected_in" : [0.07, "Bremen", "Nied"]})
df['campaigned_in'] = ["Schleswig",45,275]
df["answer"]=df["campaigned_in"]
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
  if(isinstance(row["campaigned_in"],str)==True):
    row["answer"]=row["elected_in"]
df.head()
```

Updated df look like:

```
    elected_in  campaigned_in   answer
0   0.07        Schleswig       0.07
1   Bremen      45              45
2   Nied        275             275
```

Comment: Fantastic! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Changed so that output is string format

```
def merge(e,c):
    if str(e).isnumeric(): 
        return e     
    elif str(c).isnumeric():
        return c
    else:
        return np.nan

data = {'elected_in':['007', 'Bremen', 'test1', 182],
         'campaigned_in_':['sh-h', np.nan, '043', 'test2']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: merge(x.elected_in, x.campaigned_in_), axis = 1)
```

output:

```
elected_in  campaigned_in_  new_column
0   007        sh-h         007
1   Bremen     NaN          NaN
2   test1      043          043
3   182        test2        182
```